# My new environment variables on Windows 10 are not working though I can set new ones

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

I set a new environment variable but I cannot execute.
Below is an example from my command line trying to call `ssh`.
`ssh` is installed correctly and I can execute it fine from the command line when I am in its path. But I cannot call it anywhere else, though I have set the environment variable for it.

From the command line...

```
// showing that the ssh environment variable is set
(base) C:\Users\ooo>echo %ssh%
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH-Win64\ssh.exe

// Though I can't call it from here    
(base) C:\Users\ooo>ssh
'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

// Not with `ssh` and not with `ssh.exe`
(base) C:\Users\ooo>ssh.exe
'ssh.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

// I cd into the path `ssh.exe` resides
(base) C:\Users\ooo>cd C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH-Win64\

// and only then can I run `ssh`
(base) C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH-Win64>ssh
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
           [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]
```

I have the ssh envirsonment variable set for the user and for the system.
I have tried just setting it for one or the other and both. I always have the same problem as above. It's as if there is absolutely no environment variable set.
I have this problem with any environment variable I need to set. Some commands install their own variables, which work fine on the command line but I cannot set my own for some reason.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you type `ssh` Windows searches all directories in the `PATH` environment variable to look for something to execute, like `ssh.exe`, `ssh.com`, `ssh.bat`, ...

I think the directory `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH-Win64` is not in your path and so Windows doesn't find your `ssh.exe`.

You can e.g.

- Add the path to your `PATH` environment variable
- Try to call `%ssh%` (or better `"%ssh%"`) instead of just `ssh`

Comment: I've added it to the `Path` in the user variables. When I tried adding it to `Path` in the system variables I get a message that says "This environment variable is too large. This dialog allows setting values up to 2047 characters long." I can't even delete anything from the system `Path` variable. I get the same message.

Comment: Hang on... I found [this](https://imgur.com/LuA7IT5) in my `Path` for system environment variables. I changed the `openssh-win64` folder name to `openssh` and I can call ssh from anywhere now. Still, my `Path` is jacked up. I'm having problems with other programs too.